# Rotate view below modal view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController`(called `MainViewController`) which presents modally a semi-transparent view (`HelpOverlayViewController`):

```
HelpOverlayViewController *helpOverlayViewController = [[HelpOverlayViewController alloc] init];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
helpOverlayViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:helpOverlayViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If the user rotates the device while the `HelpOverlayViewController` is shown it only rotates `HelpOverlayViewController` and not the `MainViewController` i.e. the parent controller. This is a problem since `HelpOverlayViewController` is semi-transparent and `MainViewController` is visible below it.

Both controllers have the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

They both rotate fine independently.

Is there some way I can force the underlaying view controller to rotate when the modal view does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do know that issues like this will likely be largely resolved with iOS 6 as it has a different model for handling rotations.

However, that doesn't help you now.  You might be best off just making your HelpOverlay a UIView and not a UIViewController.  You can add this semi-transparent view onto the top of your MainViewController (or any other).  You can still create an animation (like a fade-in) when adding this subview to your view hierarchy.  With this model, you'll no longer have any issues with rotations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do know that I can add my overlay as an UIView, but I am reluctant to do so as my HelpOverlayController contains quite a bit bit of logic. But I will keep that suggestion in mind as a back up if I fail to find another solution.

Comment: I ended up adding the overlay as a subview.

Comment: @NobleK, you could probably still use the ViewController, alloc/init it, but don't do a presentModal ... just add ViewController.view as your subview

Comment: Yes, that's what I did :) However, it is not perfect. I have an additional view which is also child of the `MainViewController`. This view slides in from side just after the help overlay has been added, which means that it slides on top of the `HelpOverlayViewController.view`. I have tried sending the help view to front, but with no luck. I naturally didn't have this problem when adding the help overlay with presentModal.